# How to call multiple requests at the same time in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

How to call multiple requests at the same time in Retrofit 2

I have 2 different api, and I want to call them at the same time. How can I do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `RxJava`'s `zip` operator (you can for example define your Retrofit api methods to return `Observable`s)

Comment: an example https://stackoverflow.com/q/30219877/2267723

Answer (score 1):

You could use `enqueue` method of `retrofit2` for asynchronously calling multiple request at the same time.

Here is the documentation for the `enqueue`:

> /**
>   * Asynchronously send the request and notify {@code callback} of its response or if an error
>   * occurred talking to the server, creating the request, or processing the response.
>   */
>       void enqueue(Callback callback);

Here is the pseudo code how you could do that:

```
Call<MyResponse> call = retroService.getSomeData();
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(
  public void onFailure(
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. This is calling A REQUEST and waiting for the result.

Comment: No it doesnt wait for the Response, Purpose of enqueue is Asynchronous it doesnt wait for the result to come, next consecutive statements are executed.

Answer (score -1):

Just create an observer that pass parameters of the two servers.
Help the code below

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization",
                    Credentials.basic("aUsername", "aPassword"));

            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
.client(okHttpClient)
.build();
```

[Font](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)