# How to nest two retrofit calls in RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-android

I have two observables `apiService.getFeed()` & `apiService.getProfile()`
I want to load both data in same screen & inorder to do that and handle errors I need to call `apiService.getProfile()` after `apiService.getFeed()`.

I have looked up a lot of examples but most of it seem to use flatMap & am not sure if we can use it especially because the two observable are of different class types and both are independent in terms of values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator . this might help you

Comment: See the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependend-sub-flows).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would nest two `Retrofit` calls with `RxJava2`'s `flatMap`:

```
    apiService.getFeed(param1, param2, ...)
            .flatMap(result -> apiService.getProfile(param1, param2, ...))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> {
                //do something here
            }, throwable -> {
                view.showErrorMessage(throwable.getMessage());
            });
```

But if it's two different observable types, you can also use different variants of flatMap:

- `flatMap` - returns a `Single`
- `flatMapCompletable` - returns a `Completable`
- `flatMapMaybe` - returns a `Maybe`
- `flatMapObservable` - returns an `Observable`
- `flatMapPublisher` - returns a `Flowable`

Comment: Thanks , will get back after trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Return your retrofit responses as Observable, then use the zip operator.  http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

When one api call has dependency on the other api call, zip operator is the ideal since the Zip operator combines the emission of two observables in order.

```
Observable <String> feed = apiService.getFeed("param");
Observable <String> profile = apiService.getProfile("param");

Observable.zip(
        feed, profile,
        new Func2<String, String, ResultType>() {

           @Override
           public ResultType call(String feedResponse, 
           String profileResponse) {
              // Do something with the feedResponse
              // Do something with the profileResponse
              // Return something with ResultType
              return something;
           }
        }).subscribe(
            //Once requests process are done
           new Consumer<Object>() {
               @Override
               public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                   //on successful completion of the request
               }
           },
           new Consumer<Throwable>() {
               @Override
               public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {
                   //on error 
               }
           });
```