# Combine synchronous and asynchronous observables

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Say that I have 5 observables, all of them are retrofit api call (one is for login)

Now i want to login, after that run all 4 other observables *at the same time* when the login progress has been finished.

Is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rxjava Android how to use the Zip operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here code sample using `rx` on `Kotlin`

```
login()//need return Observable
    .flatMap{ result->
       //maby init calls observables     
       zip(firstCallObservable, secondObservable, thirdCallObservanle,fouthCallObservable){
       first, second, third, fouth->
          //do something with data           
        }}
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the login come first according to the question? But it goes in the right direction imo