# Zip more than 9 Observables in rxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, observable, reactivex

Faced the situation when it is necessary to make 10-12 small parallel queries and combine the results. But if there is a zip method that allows you to combine up to 9 Observables, then how to do more I do not understand. I tried using zip Method

`public static <T, R> Observable<R> zip(Iterable<? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> sources, Function<? super Object[], ? extends R> zipper)`

but but got an error

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to io.reactivex.ObservableSource`

Attempts look like this

```
List<Observable> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(orderRepository.getOne(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getTwo(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getThree(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getFour(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getFive());
list.add(orderRepository.getSix(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getSeven(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getEight());
list.add(orderRepository.getNine());
list.add(orderRepository.getTen(54, "id"));
list.add(orderRepository.getEleven(54, "id"));
Observable.fromIterable(list);

return Observable.zip(list,
        new Function<Object[], OrderModel>() {
            @Override
            public OrderModel apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                Logger.trace("objects = ", objects);
                return new OrderModel();
            }
        });
```

Please give an example of how to do this in Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rxjava Android how to use the Zip operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator)

Comment: For which line do you get the `ClassCastException`? Why do you have that `Observable.fromIterable(list)` that you don't use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    Observable one = Observable.zip(
        orderRepository.getOne(54, "id"), 
        orderRepository.getTwo(54, "id"),
        // Etc up to five (I think)
        Function zipper
    );

    Observable two = Observable.zip(
        one, orderRepository.getSix(54, "id"),
        orderRepository.getSeven(54, "id"),
        // Etc up to five,
        Function zipper
    );
```

Rinse and repeat until you get all your observables zipped together.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example how to use Observable#zip overload with Iterable. You get a new Object[] of results, because Java generics does not Support new T[].

In this example you see a List of Observables of T, which will be used in Observable#zip. The zipper-function will cast each Object to String and return a List of T. You get Observable> as a result.

Also I would suggest you make sure, that given List of Observable is not empty. When a empty List of Observables is given to Observable#zip, it will complete immediately without emitting anything (thanks to @akarnokd). Or you could just use Observable#switchIfEmpty in order to provide a fallback value (e.g. empty list)

```
@Test
  void x() {
    Observable<String> z1 = Observable.just("1");
    Observable<String> z2 = Observable.just("2");
    Observable<String> z3 = Observable.just("3");

    List<Observable<String>> observables = Arrays.asList(z1, z2, z3);

    Observable<List<String>> zip =
        Observable.zip(
            observables,
            objects -> {
              List<String> resultList =
                  Stream.of(objects).map(o -> (String) o).collect(Collectors.toList());

              return resultList;
            });

    zip.test()
        .assertNoErrors()
        .assertComplete()
        .assertValueCount(1)
        .assertValueAt(
            0,
            r -> {
              assertThat(r).contains("1", "2", "3");

              return true;
            });
  }
```

Comment: But what if all element in list have different types. For example, one Observable<OrderEntity>, two Observable<List<Types>>? When I receive objects in a function, how can I tell what is what?

Comment: Zipping an empty list of Observables [will complete](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableZip.java#L66) immediately.

Comment: @Андрей, all types must be the same, when using Observable#zip in order to cast safely. You could split the results with same types to several Observables (e.g. Observable<List<T>> obs1$ = ... , Observable<T> obs2$, ...) and use Observable.zip(obs1$, obs2$, (o1, o2) -> {}) in order to merge them all together.

Comment: But if all observables return different types of data? And such 12. How to be in this situation? These 12 requests are data from a server of different types, necessary for displaying on the application page. I do not want to do something similar to the query sequence in UI, first request this data packet, then ask for the remaining. I suspect that someone must have been confronted with situations where all 12 observed different types and it is necessary to collect them into one returned model

Answer (score 2):

```
  Observable.zip(Observable1 , Observable2 ,... Observable9  , 
    Function9<return_value_observable1 , return_value_observable2 , .... , 
    return_value_observable9 , ZipModel { ->
    }
```

Comment: Adding some commentary will go a long way to explain why this solves the OP's question. Just a code dump alone is not that helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.