# How to merge two network requests response into single object

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to retrieve data from below two API requests using retrofit client and want to display in Listview

I am getting response from both below API requests with differenr fields

In below API, coin name, coin price
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest

In below API, logo 
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info

How to combine both above request responses in separate POJO class?

CoinName.kt
data class CoinName(
      var name: String,
      var price: String
)

CoinInfo.kt
data class CoinInfo(
      var logo: String
)

I want to show coin name, coin price, logo fields in my Listview. But coin name and price is present in class CoinName and logo present in CoinInfo class

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a 3rd class that either contains info from the first 2 classes or wraps them.  Then populate the list view with instances of the 3rd class.  But that solution sounds so obvious that it suggests I am misunderstanding your problem.  Perhaps you should show us your attempt, and we can *see* what your problem really is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use zip operator and combine your responses into 3rd class. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator/30221196)