# How to check if RXJava finish or empty from queue

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a function that loop the request using Retrofit and RXJava as below

```
for (i in month..12) {
    if (Conn.connection(applicationContext)) {
        Api.create().getDateInMonth("2019-$i-01")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : Observer<DateDataResponse> {
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                override fun onNext(dateDataResponse: DateDataResponse) {
                    Log.d("OnSuccess", "success")
                }
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("onError", "error" + e.message)
                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    Log.d("onComplete", "onComplete")
                }
            })
    } else
        Log.d("onError", "No Internet Connection")
    }
}
```

so if some request error or success it will go on until the 12 request is finish. I want to detect if I already got all response from my request

Comment: you can check in onComplete if i equals to 12 then it is last api call and check after that all response is empty or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator

Comment: @NidhiDesai thank for that, I've already done that but I don't think if that's a good way to handle this situation.

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank for bringing the zip the observer but I don't think that I've to do that with this simple request

Comment: are you maintaining list to collect response for all the months?

Comment: yes. If the response is success, I appended it to an array of that model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn this into a single chain, then you can use the `onComplete()` callback to verify that all your requests have finished. For example:

```
Observable.range(0, 12)
    .filter { i-> Conn.connection(applicationContext) }
    .flatMap { i -> Api.create().getDateInMonth("2019-$i-01") } 
    .subscribeOn(io())
    .observeOn(mainThread())
    .subscribe({ i-> }, { t-> }, {/*onComplete*/ })
```

Comment: thank you. this seems like a proper way to handle the request, I'll try it then I'll let you know