# How to pass an object from `flatMap` to `subscribe` in a chain?

Tags: java, rx-java

How to pass an object from `flatMap` to `subscribe` in a chain? And in the code snippet below how would the `blog` object can be accessed down the chain?

```
    Single<HttpResponse<JsonNode>> singleHttpClient = httClient.post();
    singleHttpClient .toObservable().flatMap(httpResponse -> {
        if(httpResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
            JsonNode responseNode = httpResponse.getBody();
            List<JSONObject> blogObjects = iterateFrom(responseNode.getObject().getJSONArray("blogs"))
        }
        return Observable.fromIterable(blogObjects).toList().toObservable();
    }).flatMap(jsonObjects -> Observable.fromIterable(jsonObjects))
            .flatMap(jsonObject -> {
                return Observable.just(new Blog(jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("guid")));
            }).flatMap(blog -> {
                Single<HttpResponse<JsonNode>> singleHttpClient2 = httpClient2.post();
                singleHttpClient2.getParams().put("guid", blog.getImageGuid());
                return singleHttpClient2.postAsBinary().toObservable();
            }).subscribe(javaScriptObjectHttpResponse -> {
                JavaScriptObject jsoBody = javaScriptObjectHttpResponse.getBody();
                doSomethingWith(blog, jsBody); // How to access `blog` from here?
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zipWith` method like below.Create variable in `Blog` object that hold your blog data response from server and create getter and setter for that data variable.

```
Single<HttpResponse<JsonNode>> singleHttpClient = httClient.post();
    singleHttpClient .toObservable().flatMap(httpResponse -> {
        if(httpResponse.getStatus() == 200) {
            JsonNode responseNode = httpResponse.getBody();
            List<JSONObject> blogObjects = iterateFrom(responseNode.getObject().getJSONArray("blogs"))
        }
        return Observable.fromIterable(blogObjects).toList().toObservable();
    }).flatMap(jsonObjects -> Observable.fromIterable(jsonObjects))
            .flatMap(jsonObject -> {
                return Observable.just(new Blog(jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("guid")));
            }).flatMap(blog -> {
        Single<HttpResponse<JsonNode>> singleHttpClient2 = httpClient2.post();
        singleHttpClient2.getParams().put("guid", blog.getImageGuid());
        return Observable.zipWith(singleHttpClient2.postAsBinary().toObservable(), (Blog blog, HttpResponse data)->blog.setData(data));
    }).subscribe(blog -> {
        doSomethingWith(blog); // How to access `blog` from here?
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In project-reactor an operator named `zip` exists for binding Monos and Fluxes (similar to Observables in rx-java) so that multiple items can be passed down (as a Tuple) the pipeline.

Similar operator should exist for rx-java.

Helpful stack-overflow question, [Rxjava Android how to use the Zip operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30219877)