# Combine three APIs' result in RxKotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin

I have a function in repository that calls three APIs which return three different type of Objects.

```
fun scanSource(code: String) =
    firstApi.DataV11Get(code)
        .flatMap {
            firstApi.sccGet(it.sscc)
        }
        .flatMap {
            lastApi.lsccGet(it.id)
        }
```

currently it is only returning the result of last API in the ViewModel .Now I want to have result of all of these in viewmodel.

plus the api must be sequential as they are using the data from the last API.

Also each API returns a different Object type.And I want all of three objects once all three calls are finished.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Declare this funtion in your Api repo

```
   fun getJobs(contractor_id: String): Observable<JobListModel> {
    return Observable.zip(
        apiInterface.pendingJobs(contractor_id, 0, 5),
        apiInterface.activeJobs(contractor_id, 0, 5),
        apiInterface.completedJobs(contractor_id, 0, 5),
        apiInterface.cancelledJobs(contractor_id, 0, 5),
        Function4<PendingJobResponseModel, ActiveJobResponseModel, CompletedJobResponseModel, CancelledJobResponseModel, JobListModel> { p, a, c, ca ->
            JobListModel(p, a, c, ca)
        }
    )
}
```

This is the method to make zip to multiple requests and model.

Please refer this link for more detailed explanation [Rxjava Android how to use the Zip operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator)

Job ListModel Class which maps all responses

```
class JobListModel(
val pendingJobResponseModel: PendingJobResponseModel,
val activeJobResponseModel: ActiveJobResponseModel,
val completedJobResponseModel: CompletedJobResponseModel,
val cancelledJobResponseModel: CancelledJobResponseModel) : Serializable
```

Comment: what is JobListModel?

Comment: It is basically a model class constructor which takes all 4 responses

Comment: Oh you meant a Custom Class? Nice

Comment: But what if activeJobs() API needs a value from the object returned from pendingJobs() ?

Comment: So you can call that Api first and take the value and make zip of rest two

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209515/discussion-between-syeda-zunaira-and-afzal-khan).