# Retrofit: How to wait until request call completes before executing next line of code?

Tags: android, rest, asynchronous, retrofit

I have 2 REST request methods; `getA()` and `getB()`. Both are asynchronous calls using `call.enqueue()`. 
 
 I cannot call `getB()` until I have the results from `getA()`.
In `onCreateView()`, I would call `getA()` and `getB()` consecutively. But, `getB()` would fail because it does not have the results from `getA()` yet. A way around this problem is, I could call `getB()` inside `getA()`, but I don't think that's clean coding. 

Is there a way to wait until the request from `getA()` is completed before calling `getB()` in `onCreateView()`?

Answer (score 1):

Call `getB()` from within the `onResponse` callback retrofit provides

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Thing>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Thing> call, Response<Thing> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                callB();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Thing> call, Throwable t) {
            // handle failure
        }
    });
```

The above will work, however, I'm a strong advocate for RxJava when handling Api calls with retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ZIP` operator from RxJava

[Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

And example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator)

Comment: I'm looking into it, but I am not understanding how it works. Could you explain how does using the `zip` operator from RXJava make the main thread to pause until the request has completed before resuming?