# Multiple Retrofit requests dependent on each other in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, rx-java

I have three API calls in which two are dependent on each other.

I have setted the following endpoints:

```
interface WeatherApi {

    @GET("/data/2.5/onecall")
    fun getWeather(
        @Query("lat") lat: Double,
        @Query("lon") lon: Double,
        @Query("exclude") exclude: String,
        @Query("units") units: String,
        @Query("appid") appKey: String
    ): Observable<WeatherModel>

    @GET("/geo/1.0/direct")
    fun getCoordinates(
        @Query("q") cityName: String,
        @Query("appid") appKey: String
    ): Observable<LocationModel>

    @GET("geo/1.0/reverse")
    fun getNameForLocation(
        @Query("lat") lat: Double,
        @Query("lon") lon: Double,
        @Query("appid") appKey: String
    ): Observable<LocationModel>

}
```

and

```
interface PlacesApi {

    @GET("/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json")
    fun getPlaceId(
        @Query("input") cityName: String,
        @Query("inputtype") inputType: String,
        @Query("fields") fields: String,
        @Query("key") appKey: String
    ): Observable<PlacesModel>

}
```

My repository looks as follows:

```
class WeatherRepository constructor(
    private val weatherService: WeatherApi,
    private val placesService: PlacesApi,
) {

    fun getCoordinates(cityName: String, appKey: String) =
        weatherService.getCoordinates(cityName, appKey)

    fun getWeather(lat: Double, lon: Double, exclude: String, units: String, appKey: String) =
        weatherService.getWeather(lat, lon, exclude, units, appKey)

    fun getPlaceId(placeName: String, appKey:String) =
        placesService.getPlaceId(placeName, "textquery", "photos", appKey)

}
```

Right now in ViewModel I would like to fetch all needed data (three models). So I should have some method, in which I will be doing all three requests one after another, as follows:

```
locationModel = weatherRepository.getCoordinates(city, BuildConfig.WEATHER_API_KEY)
weatherModel = weatherRepository.getWeather(locationModel[0].lat!!, locationModel[0].lon!!)
placesModel = weatherRepository.getPlaceId(weatherModel, BuildConfig.PLACES_API_KEY)
```

and after all that I need to create new model, which includes all fetched data. Something like:

```
val cityModel = CityModel(
    locationModel,
    weatherModel,
    placesModel
)
```

Does anybody know how to do something like this using RxJava in Kotlin?

Comment: `zipWith` comes to mind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219877/rxjava-android-how-to-use-the-zip-operator

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this. The one that comes to mind is not super elegant. You can use [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html), but you will need to keep track of your models along the way so you can build the last model. You can try using [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/).

Here's the whole idea:

```
 weatherRepository.getCoordinates(city, BuildConfig.WEATHER_API_KEY)
     .flatMap { locationModel ->
       weatherRepository.getWeather(locationModel[0].lat!!, locationModel[0].lon!!)
         .map { locationModel to it }
     }
     .flatMap { (locationModel, weatherModel) ->
        weatherRepository.getPlaceId(weatherModel, BuildConfig.PLACES_API_KEY)
          .map {
            CityModel(
              locationModel,
              weatherModel,
              it
            )
          }
     }
```

So first you `getCoordinates` and use the result to get the weather. Using [to](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) you create a Pair that gets "piped" into the next `flatMap`.

Once inside the last `flatMap` you destructure the pair into `locationModel` and `weatherModel` and use them to fetch the place id.

With everything now you can simply build your `CityModel`.

Comment: I would use `switchMap` but I think these are really `Single` rather than `Observable` so yeah, `flatMap` would work too.

Comment: Given that they're retrofit calls I don't think the source observable would change. I don't see why a `switchMap` would behave differently in this particular case.

Comment: If you assume the Observable only emits once then it wouldn't behave differently, but it would if it emits more than once. As I said in my previous comment, if there's only one emission they should be `Single`

Comment: I understand. I don't know any way an observable returned from Retrofit would ever emit more than one element. Maybe it's possible, I just never came across it. That's what I meant. In that case, `switchMap` wouldn't give any different behaviour that `flatMap`. Indeed, if this is the case, they should be `Single`s

Answer (score 0):

You can try the share() operator. Something like below:

```
locationModelObservable = weatherRepository.getCoordinates(city, BuildConfig.WEATHER_API_KEY).share()
weatherModelObservable = locationModel.flatMap { weatherRepository.getWeather(it[0].lat!!, it[0].lon!!) }.share()
placesModelObservable = weatherModel.flatMap { weatherRepository.getPlaceId(it, BuildConfig.PLACES_API_KEY) }

zip(locationModelObservable, weatherModelObservable, placesModelObservable) { .. }
```